# Improper Neutralization of Script-Related HTML Tags in a Web Page (Basic XSS)

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, xss

I have generated a Varacode report for my visualforce Page showing flaws in that page.Below is my page and class please suggest how to fix ?

In Page at line number 5 showing the Flaw where Script tag starts.

My Page :

```html
<apex:page standardController="Call_Report__c"  extensions="RestViewCallReportCheck" lightningStylesheets="true">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:actionFunction name="CallApexMethod" action="{!RedirectEdit}" onComplete="alert('After apex method') ;"/>
    </apex:form>
    <script>
    function redirectCheck(){
        if ({!recordLocked} == true) {
            alert('Record is locked.');
            window.open("/{!Call_Report__c.Id}","_self");
        } else {
            if({!showIcddPage} == true || {!showCallReportStandard}==true){
                CallApexMethod();
            }
            else if({!showOrgPage}==true) {
                if('{!$CurrentPage.parameters.recordType}' !='') {
                    window.location.href='/{!Call_Report__c.id}/e?nooverride=1&retURL=/{!Call_Report__c.id}&RecordType='+'{!$CurrentPage.parameters.recordType}';
                } else {
                    window.location.href='/{!Call_Report__c.id}/e?nooverride=1&retURL=/{!Call_Report__c.id}';
                }
            } else{
                alert('The record you tried to Edit is restricted for public view. Please contact {!orgOwnerName}');
                window.location.href='/home/home.jsp';
            }
        }
    }
    redirectCheck();
    </script>
     </apex:page>
```

Apex Class:

```java
public class RestViewCallReportCheck {
    Public boolean showIcddPage{get; set;}
    Public boolean showCallReportStandard {get; set;} //used for call report standard record type redirect
    Public Boolean showOrgPage{get; set;}
    Public String orgOwnerName{get; set;}
    Public String crId {get;set;}
    public Call_Report__c cr{get; set;}
    Public Boolean resrtictview{get; set;}
    Public Boolean Nonresuser{get;set;}
    Public Boolean recordLocked{get;set;} //for US411711: Audit History: Call Report lockdown
    
    Id userId ;
    Boolean adminUser; //for US411711: Audit History: Call Report lockdown
    
    public RestViewCallReportCheck(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
    {
        Boolean isAdmin = false;
        Boolean isAccTeamMem = false;
        integer count=0;
        showOrgPage = true;
        resrtictview=false;
        string userId = UserInfo.getUserId();
        userId = userId.subString(0,15);
        crId = controller.getId();
        showCallReportStandard = false;
        
        //START US411711: Audit History: Call Report lockdown
        String currentUserProfile = [SELECT Name FROM Profile WHERE Id =: UserInfo.getProfileId() LIMIT 1].Name;
        
        for (String profielName : Label.User_Profile_Exclude.split(',')) {
            if (currentUserProfile == profielName) {
                adminUser = true;
            }
        }
        
        if (adminUser == false) {
            recordLocked = Approval.isLocked(crId);
        }
        //END US411711: Audit History: Call Report lockdown
        
        //CR-571 Starts
        // Call_Report__c cr = [select RecordType.DeveloperName, RecordTypeId, Restricted_View__c,CW_RestrictSelf__c,Related_Organization__r.Coverage_segment__c,Restricted_ViewF__c,Id,iCDD_ID__c, Assigned_To__r.Name, Related_Organization__r.ownerId, Related_Organization__r.Restricted_View__c,Related_Organization__c from Call_Report__c where id=:crId limit 1];
        cr = [select RecordType.DeveloperName, RecordTypeId, Restricted_View__c,CW_RestrictSelf__c,Related_Organization__r.Coverage_segment__c,Restricted_ViewF__c,Id,iCDD_ID__c, Assigned_To__r.Name, Related_Organization__r.ownerId, Related_Organization__r.Restricted_View__c,Related_Organization__c from Call_Report__c where id=:crId limit 1];
        for(AccountTeamMember accTM :[Select Id from AccountTeamMember where UserId=: userId and AccountId=: cr.Related_Organization__c]){
            isAccTeamMem = true;
        }
        
        
        for(RestrictedClient__c R : RestrictedClient__c.getAll().values()){   
            if(r.name==userId && cr.Related_Organization__r.Coverage_segment__c == 'Key Client' && cr.Related_Organization__r.Restricted_View__c == true){
                count = count+1;
                system.debug('********Restrictflag3**********'+resrtictview);
            }
        }
        if(count > 0){
            showOrgPage = true;
        }
        //CR-571 Ends
        /*       
         for(RestrictedClient__c R : RestrictedClient__c.getAll().values()){

        {

          System.debug('---------Debug-----------');
             if(R.name == userId)
        {

        count=count+1; 
        }  

}
}

if(count >0) {
NonResuser = true;
system.debug('**NonResuser***'+NonResuser);

}
else {
NonResuser =false;
}
*/
        List<Profile> pro = [Select Id,Name From Profile p where Id =: UserInfo.getProfileId()];
        String profileName = pro[0].Name;
          // Pooja-SCRM-15534 - Added System administrator with JML profile
        List<Profile> prof = [Select Id, Name From Profile Where Name = 'System Administrator' or Name = 'Barclays: System Administrator with JML' or Name = 'Barclays: System Administrator' or Name = 'Compliance Team' order by Name];
        system.debug('@@icdd: '+cr.iCDD_ID__c);
        if(cr.iCDD_ID__c != null){      
            if(profileName != null && profileName.startsWith('BB:')){
                showIcddPage = true;
            }
            else if(profileName != null && profileName.contains('BB Barclays:')){
                showIcddPage = true;
            }
            else if(profileName != null && profileName.equals('System Administrator')){
                showIcddPage = true;
            }
            system.debug('@@showIcddPage: '+showIcddPage);
        }
        
        else if(prof != null && prof.size() == 4) {
            if(String.valueOf(prof.get(0).Id).equals(UserInfo.getProfileId()) || String.valueOf(prof.get(1).Id).equals(UserInfo.getProfileId()) || String.valueOf(prof.get(2).Id).equals(UserInfo.getProfileId()) || String.valueOf(prof.get(3).Id).equals(UserInfo.getProfileId())){
                isAdmin = true;
            }
        }
        system.debug('@@isAdmin: '+isAdmin);
        List<String> restrictedUserList = new List<String>();
        List<RestrictedAccountAccess__c> userAccList = RestrictedAccountAccess__c.getall().values();
        for(RestrictedAccountAccess__c userObj:userAccList) {
            if(userObj.Id__c != null){
                restrictedUserList.add(userObj.Id__c)  ;
            }
        }
        if(!restrictedUserList.contains(userId)){
        if(cr.CW_RestrictSelf__c == true && userId!=cr.Related_Organization__r.ownerId && !isAccTeamMem && !isAdmin && count==0){
            showOrgPage = false;
            orgOwnerName = cr.Assigned_To__r.Name;
        }
        
        if(cr.Related_Organization__r.Restricted_View__c == true && userId!=cr.Related_Organization__r.ownerId && !isAdmin && !isAccTeamMem && count == 0){//CR-571
            if([select count() from Call_Report_Attendee__c where Call_Report__c =: crId and Attendee__c=:userId  ]==0){
                showOrgPage = false;
                orgOwnerName = cr.Assigned_To__r.Name;
            }
        } 
        system.debug('@@showOrgPage: '+showOrgPage);
        }
        //call report Standard record type redirect on edit functionality
        if (cr.RecordType.DeveloperName == 'Standard' || cr.RecordType.DeveloperName == 'GFI_Standard') {
            showCallReportStandard = true;
        }
        
        //call report Standard record type
       if (cr.RecordType.DeveloperName != Label.MobilePaymentCallreport && profileName.contains(Label.Mobile_Payment_Profile )) {
            showOrgPage = false; 
           orgOwnerName = cr.Assigned_To__r.Name;
        }
        
        
    }
    
    public PageReference RedirectEdit() {
        
        PageReference newPage = null;
        
        if(showIcddPage == true){
            newPage = Page.iCDDEdit;
            newPage.getParameters().put('id',crId);
        }
        else if(showCallReportStandard) {
            List<string> names = new list<string>();/*Maanas Lightning ChangeStart*/
            
            for(Lightning_Profiles__c lp : Lightning_Profiles__c.getAll().values()){
                names.add(lp.Profile_Name_del__c);
            }
            
            String userName = [Select Name from Profile where Id = :UserInfo.getProfileId()].name;
            
            if(names.contains(userName)){
                newPage = Page.Content_CallReport_Lightning;
            }else{                    
                newPage = Page.Content_CallReport;
            }/*Maanas Lightning Change End*/
            
            system.debug('calling call report classic'); 
            //newPage = Page.Content_CallReport;
            newPage.getParameters().put('Id',crId);
            newPage.getParameters().put('retURL',crId);  
            newPage.getParameters().put('RecordType',cr.RecordTypeId);                              
        } 
        return newPage.setRedirect(true); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Nitesh and welcome to SFSE!

XSS attack can happen here, if a user enters a malicious code in record type Id parameter.

To resolve this issue, use either `JSENCODE` or `JSINHTMLCODE` formulas as:

Unescaped Output and Formulas in Visualforce Pages: `{!JSENCODE($CurrentPage.parameters.recordType)}`

Also doesn't hurt to include other variables from controller to be really sure, and controller property could be driven by page parameters:

```js
function redirectCheck(){
    if ({!recordLocked} == true) {
        alert('Record is locked.');
        window.open("/{!JSENCODE(Call_Report__c.Id)}","_self");
    } else {
        if({!JSENCODE(showIcddPage)} == true || {!JSENCODE(showCallReportStandard)}==true){
            CallApexMethod();
        }
        else if({!JSENCODE(showOrgPage)}==true) {
            if('{!JSENCODE($CurrentPage.parameters.recordType)}' !='') {
                window.location.href='/{!JSENCODE(Call_Report__c.id)}/e?nooverride=1&retURL=/{!JSENCODE(Call_Report__c.id)}&RecordType='+'{!JSENCODE($CurrentPage.parameters.recordTyp)e}';
            } else {
                window.location.href='/{!Call_Report__c.id}/e?nooverride=1&retURL=/{!Call_Report__c.id}';
            }
        } else{
            alert('The record you tried to Edit is restricted for public view. Please contact {!JSENCODE(orgOwnerName)}');
            window.location.href='/home/home.jsp';
        }
    }
}
```

Refer [`Unescaped Output and Formulas in Visualforce Pages`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_intro.htm). This help page does not work properly for me, refer to the Visualforce PDF for this topic.